# Automate clicking buttons on one page and then another page using vba

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I am trying to work on something that clicks a button\line on a page, then clicks on others when the new page loads. I can get my vba to click the first button/link, but then when trying to click the next I am getting the error

> Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set

Now I have to be honest, the code I do have is from research, and by no means do I understand it fully, I have searched all over trying to rectify the 2nd click, but nothing seems to be working.

the code I have so far is

```
Public Sub SHAREREPORTING()

Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim Button As Object
Dim Button2 As Object


Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "URL"
Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

Set Button = IE.Document.getElementById("b1_pki")
Button.Click

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

SendKeys "mypassword" , True
SendKeys "{ENTER}", True

Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

Set Button2 = IE.Document.getElementById("seite-itm-2")

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

Button2.Click

End Sub
```

the code for the 2 buttons ( I am calling them buttons/links, because I'm not too sure what they are, I don't understand javascript) I am trying to click at the moment is

Button1/Link1

```
<A onclick=loginViaPKI(); onkeypress=loginViaPKI(); id=b1_pki title="Log on with PKI - Button - To activate, press spacebar." class=urBtnEmph hideFocus style="WHITE-SPACE: nowrap" href="javascript:void(0);" ct="Button">Log on with PKI</A>
```

Button2/Link2

```
<TD onclick="return htmlbSL(this,7,'seite:sel_tab_2','','3','sel_tab_2')" id=seite-itm-2 class=urTbsLabelOff onkeydown="if (sapUrMapi_checkKey(event,'keydown',new Array('32'))){return htmlbSL(this,7,'seite:sel_tab_2','','3','sel_tab_2')};sapUrMapi_TabStrip_keySelect('seite',2,4,event);" noWrap><SPAN id=seite-itm-2-txt title="Bookmarks     " class=urTbsTxtOff>Bookmarks </SPAN></TD>
```

Answer (score 0):

The program requires references to the following:

```
1 Microsoft Internet Controls
2. Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

The Internet control is used to browse the webpage and the HTML Objects are used to identify the username and password textboxes and submit the text using the control button.

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Sub Login_2_Website()

Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim sURL As String

On Error GoTo Err_Clear
sURL = "https://www.google.com/accounts/Login"
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
oBrowser.Silent = True
oBrowser.timeout = 60
oBrowser.navigate sURL
oBrowser.Visible = True

Do
' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.Document

HTMLDoc.all.Email.Value = "sample@vbadud.com"
HTMLDoc.all.passwd.Value = "*****"

For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
If oHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next

' oBrowser.Refresh ' Refresh If Needed
Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Debug.Assert Err = 0
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank ryguy - but I think this will just login to the page - I have taken some pointers from this to improve my code, however I am trying to get my code to click something that is on the page that is loaded after the login page.

I think (and don't quote me on it) the problem lies in my code with IE being a new Internet Explorer medium, and when the 2nd page loads I am using IE.Document.